# how can i use what i imported in another component in context API with arrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

pls i wanted to use **placeInfo,reviews,detailsInfo,news** coming from data file. instead of putting **value='hello'** [[image: import { placeInfo, reviews, detailsInfo, news } from '../data';<InfoContext.Provider value={placeInfo,reviews,detailsInfo,news} >][1]]i doubt if i can use it direct like this **value={placeInfo,reviews,detailsInfo,news}** which is giving me error
or i should put it in var

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the value in an object like this `value={{placeInfo, reviews, detailsInfo, news}}`

or create the object on a separate line like this:

```
const value = {
   placeInfo,
   reviews,
   detailsInfo,
   news
};
```

Then pass it as `value={value}`